# How to use set variables option in azure classic pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

is there any way to use Set variables in scripts azure classic pipeline?

Looking this option in azure classic pipeline
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash

Answer (score 1):

Add a Bash or PowerShell script to your pipeline.

The examples below will create a variable called `myVar` and set its value to `foo`.

**Bash:**

```bash
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;]foo"
```

[image: Bash script]

**PowerShell:**

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;]foo"
```

[image: PowerShell script]